# How to loop array of objects using forEach?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I want to display the fields of objects using forEach, but something is not working for me.It doesn’t show me the values ??that I entered, but only the type of Object

```
Transportation[] companys = new Transportation[2];
for (int i = 0; i <=companys.Length-1; i++)
{
    companys[i] = new Transportation();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter company: ");
    companys[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter unit price: ");
    companys[i].Cost = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Weight: ");
    companys[i].Weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

}
Console.Clear();
foreach (Transportation key in companys)// here is problem
{
   Console.WriteLine("List "+companys[key]);
}
```

Comment: "here is problem" - what happens? `foreach` on an array should work fine... please be specific: what happens?

Comment: "but something is not working for me." And **what** exactly? Do you get an exception? Any compiler-error? Unspected results?

Comment: `key` isn't the index, it's the whole object. In the first loop, you will get `0` which you use to access `companys[0]`. In the second loop, `key` is `companys[0]`.

Comment: @John you should expand that as an answer, IMO

Comment: It doesn’t show me the values ​​that I entered, but only the type of Object

Comment: @Marc I have looked closer and see there's not only one issue, so I'll write an answer. :)

Comment: @John the `<=` ? the missing `new Transportation()` ?

Comment: If you use `Console.WriteLine(transportation)` it will not list all properties of this object. To achieve this, override the `ToString` method of the `Transportation` class. See [How to: Override the ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help.

```
foreach (Transportation key in companys)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("List "+ key.X);
    }
```

where X is a string property of your Transportation class.

Answer (score 1):

Each `key` in your `foreach` loop is a Transportation object instance. Since the array indexer expects an `int`, this won't work.

With `foreach`, you get each item in the list in the loop variable, `key` in your case, and handle it, such as

```
foreach (Transportation key in companys)// here is problem
{
   Console.WriteLine("List " + key.Name);
}
```

Comment: You`re duplicating my answer its better to edit it, not to post another one.

Comment: @ЛюсиенЛозанов I would have edited if it were typos or formatting, not a rewrite.